# (New?) Modal Operators for Foldable

Tags: haskell, foldable, modal-logic

This post follows in a sense [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55815807/2751851). HTNW, [in their answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55816153/2751851), defined the data type `Same` and the function `allEq`. So I thought that by defining the data type `AllDifferent`, the function `allDiff` and the derived ones `someEq` and `someDiff`, I would have obtained [a kind of modal square](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/) for `Foldable` structures.

If the result of my work is correct, how can one appropriately characterise this set of data types and functions?

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Matrix as MT  -- only for exemplification

-- EXAMPLES --
-- allEq    $ MT.fromLists ["aaa","aaa"] -> True
-- allEq    $ MT.fromLists ["aaa","daa"] -> False
-- someEq   $ MT.fromLists ["abc","dea"] -> True
-- someEq   $ MT.fromLists ["abc","def"] -> False
-- allDiff  $ MT.fromLists ["abc","def"] -> True
-- allDiff  $ MT.fromLists ["abc","dea"] -> False
-- someDiff $ MT.fromLists ["aaa","daa"] -> True
-- someDiff $ MT.fromLists ["aaa","aaa"] -> False

-- ====================== allEq ======================
-- produced by HTNW in response to my previous post.

data Same a = Vacuous | Fail | Same a
instance Eq a => Semigroup (Same a) where
    Vacuous    <> x       = x
    Fail       <> _       = Fail
    s@(Same l) <> Same r  = if l == r then s else Fail
    x          <> Vacuous = x
    _          <> Fail    = Fail

instance Eq a => Monoid (Same a) where
    mempty = Vacuous
allEq :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> Bool
allEq xs = case foldMap Same xs of
                Fail -> False
                _    -> True

-- ====================== allDiff ======================

data AllDifferent a = VacuousAD | FailAD | AllDifferent (S.Set a)
--  The lazy construction avoids taking the last union when it's not necessary, which can 
-- save a significant amount of time when folding over large trees that are 
-- pretty balanced at their roots.

instance (Eq a, Ord a) => Semigroup (AllDifferent a) where
    VacuousAD      <> x       = x
    FailAD         <> _       = FailAD
    AllDifferent l <> AllDifferent r  = if S.disjoint l r 
                                        then AllDifferent (S.union l r)
                                        else FailAD
    x              <> VacuousAD = x
    _              <> FailAD    = FailAD

instance (Eq a, Ord a) => Monoid (AllDifferent a) where
    mempty = VacuousAD
allDiff :: (Foldable f, Eq a, Ord a) => f a -> Bool
allDiff xs = case foldMap (AllDifferent . S.singleton)  xs of
                FailAD -> False
                _    -> True

-- ====================== someEq ======================

someEq :: (Foldable f, Eq a, Ord a) => f a -> Bool
someEq = not . allDiff

 -- ====================== someDiff ======================

someDiff :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> Bool 
someDiff = not . allEq
```

Comment: Side note: use `disjoint l r` instead of `null (intersection l r)` to improve performance. The former doesn't have to build a result set.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You seem to have a problem and a solution. What remains?

Comment: Also, you should include a comment explaining that making the `AllDifferent` constructor lazy avoids taking the last union when it's not necessary, which can save a significant amount of time when folding over large trees that are pretty balanced at their roots. Defend your code against careless "optimization"!

Comment: @dfeuer Thank for the suggestions; I've just modified the code. My question is a theoretical question about the kind of this modal operators. Are true modal operator like: Necessity - Possibility; Obligatory - Permissible; ecc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that your functions form a square of oppositions because they express quantification -- more specifically, quantification of a certain predicate over pairs of elements from the foldable container [note 1]. From this point of view, there being squares of oppositions involving modal operators reflects how modalities can be understood as forms of local quantification. I don't see a more direct link from your functions to the traditional modalities.

On a broader note, most approaches towards expressing modality in Haskell that I know of are mediated, on a theoretical level, by the Curry-Howard isomorphism -- see [*Interesting operators in Haskell that obey modal axioms*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49262771/2751851) for a few references on that. I have never heard about attempts to think about properties of data structures in terms of modalities; however, I don't think it is impossible for that to make sense somehow [note 2].

---

**Note 1:** I say "pairs of elements" from the vantage point that regards relations as sets of pairs. In concrete terms, I'm thinking of this out-of-competition implementation of `allEq`...

```
allEq :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> Bool
allEq xs = all (uncurry (==)) (liftA2 (,) xs' xs')
    where
    xs' = toList xs
```

... in which we check whether a certain property, namely `uncurry (==)`, holds for all pairs of elements of `xs`.

**Note 2:** For one, possible world semantics can be worked with using graphs, as vividly illustrated in [this demo](https://rkirsling.github.io/modallogic/).

Comment: Wheh you write (liftA2 (,) xs' xs') you intend  (liftA2 (,) (init xs') (tail xs')?

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Not really. If you wanted to exploit transitivity, you might write `zip (drop 1 xs') xs'` (note that is a different list applicative). My implementation above, though, is merely illustrative, and in any case if we were concerned about performance we would have to generate the pairs in a single pass through `xs` (otherwise memory retention woes await).  On a mostly unrelated note, an analogous implementation of `allDifferent` wouldn't be quite as straightforward, as `(/=)` is neither reflexive nor transitive.